# How can I create a transparent background for an object that's on top of a white background with AI?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

What I am looking to do is for those areas in red to be transparent.  However the problem is that they are placed on to of the areas in white so they do not show the background when the svgs is placed on a colored area.

Would appreciate any suggestions on if / how I can do this with Adobe Illustrator.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through [tour] to learn about our community; then look over [ask] and [answer] a question to see what makes a good query, and how best to frame it. I must admit to being *very* confused by your post: you want the red areas transparent, but you've placed them above (stacking order) white background elements so that when the resulting `SVG` is placed on a coloured background, that background does NOT show through - in other words, to prevent them from behaving like transparent items. Perhaps you can [edit] your question to make it clearer and less confusing?

Answer (score 3):

Select all, then use the Shape Builder tool while holding down <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> to delete the red pieces

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to create compound paths from your different objects-

for example, the text bubble and the 3 rectangular "text" lines-
select them all with the black arrow (selection) tool and go to Object> Compound Path> Make.

If you want to modify any of the compound path objects separately later you can select and go to Object> Compound Path> Release and change any of the individual objects- then re-make the compound path

[image]